# myobj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); give an error in my project

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm newbie in javascript and I have a problem to parse Json

I read the similar question but none of them give me a correct answers.

in my code there are below functions that should parse a json file called wifi.txt when page loading.

```
function responsewifi(){
    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status ==200){
        myobj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        
        document.getElementById("SSID").value = myobj.SSID;
        document.getElementById("APKEY").value = myobj.APKEY;
        document.getElementById("ESPAPNAME").value = myobj.ESPAPNAME;
        document.getElementById("ESPAPKEY").value = myobj.ESPAPKEY;
        var wifimodes = myobj.wifimode;
        if(wifimodes=="STAmode"){document.getElementById("STAmode").checked = true;}
        if(wifimodes=="APmode"){document.getElementById("APmode").checked = true;}
        if(wifimodes=="MULTImode"){document.getElementById("MULTImode").checked = true;}
    }
}
function processwificonfig()
{
    regwifi.open("get","wifi.txt",true);
    regwifi.onreadystatechange = responsewifi;
    regwifi.send();
}

processwificonfig();
```

the problem is that when page load the code `myobj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` doesn't work and its below code doesn't work too.

I try `consol.log` and `alert("test")` in every line of top code but just code before `myobj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` work correctly

I get the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.responsewifi
```

myobj is a var

```
I code this for a NODEMCU ESP8266 project.
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: Use a debugger, set a breakpoint in `if(this.readyState==4 && this.status ==200){` and analyze the values and code flow.

Comment: [doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem .What is the value of `this.responseText`? What is the value of `myobj`? Is this yet another example of "The JSON data structure has an array you are ignoring?" error.

Answer (score 1):

thanks you F. Müller

I write this answer for who has this problem as me

I tried for about 2 days to solve this problem

as F. Müller said problem was finding a correct json file

I realized that in spiffs memory of esp8266 there is a slash`/` before files name

here I have to write
`regwifi.open("get","/wifi.txt",true);`
instead of
`regwifi.open("get","wifi.txt",true);`
in `processwificonfig()` function

and thats it

Answer (score 0):

Try working with this... use as starting point:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p id="SSID"></p>
  <p id="APKEY"></p>
  <p id="ESPAPNAME"></p>
  <p id="ESPAPKEY"></p>

  <script>
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  method = "GET",
  url = "wifi.txt";
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
        // The request has been completed successfully
        // console.log(xhr.responseText);
        myobj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("SSID").innerText = myobj.SSID;
        document.getElementById("APKEY").innerText = myobj.APKEY;
        document.getElementById("ESPAPNAME").innerText = myobj.ESPAPNAME;
        document.getElementById("ESPAPKEY").innerText = myobj.ESPAPKEY;
        // wifimodes next...
      } else {
        console.log('Oh no! There has been an error with the request!');
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
  </script>

 <!-- wifi.txt file content:
  {
    "SSID": "777",
    "APKEY": "333",
    "ESPAPNAME": "neo",
    "ESPAPKEY": "222"
  }
  -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get this error again```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange ((index):398:22)```

Comment: @BAli There is something wrong with JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) i.e. the file you are trying to read does not comply to JSON-Standards. Make sure the file is valid JSON. Or the xhr.responseText is empty. Check for that as well.